# Get Age by birthdate onkeyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

i create script get Age by birthdate on keyup but
  i have a problem. because, when i type 
  example : i type : 1955-11-13  this result show **NaN**

**This is my script :**

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
 var fulldate = document.getElementById('fulldate');
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
        $('#fulldate').keyup(function(){
        var birthdate = fulldate.value; 
        var cur = new Date();
        var diff = cur-birthdate;
        var age = Math.floor(diff/31536000000);
           result.value = age;
   });
 });
</script>


Date : <span><input   id="fulldate"  type="text"   value="1995-11-13" /></span>
<br/><br/>
Age  : <span><input  id="result" type="text"  /></span>
```

But if not using keyup this script run correctly

**This script run correctly :**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
        var birthdate = new Date("1995/11/13");
        var cur = new Date();
        var diff = cur-birthdate;
        var age = Math.floor(diff/31536000000);
           alert(age);

 });
</script>
```

Help me thank's

Comment: Show the relevant part of your HTML

Comment: Try `var birthdate = Date(fulldate.value); `

Comment: I'm edit see again :)

Comment: Have you noticed my 2nd comment?

Comment: when i show result var dif   :  alert(dif)  
this show NaN

Comment: previously i alreadt alert  birthdate   and cur
ant this show..
but i alert dif  show "NaN"

Comment: Although your question was solved, I should point out this calculation is not going to always give the correct age as people actually count them; try a value like 2011-05-11 (given that today is 2015-05-10) and see.

Comment: Getting the real age is simple though: `var diff = new Date(Date.now() - new Date('2011-05-11')); var age = diff.getFullYear() - 1970;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At **Document Ready** function you use `var birthdate = new Date(fulldate.value)` but at **Keyup** function you use only `var birthdate = fulldate.value`. It makes the difference.

Use `var birthdate = new Date(fulldate.value)` to get your result.

You can take a look at the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/80hrn55f/

Comment: But, when i textbox birthdate, i add plugin datetimepicker
this age not show, :(

Comment: Done, i only change keyup ->  .click